# Firebase Cloud function timeout

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using new cloud functions functionality of firebase. For a http type of method, default timeout duration for the method is 60 seconds and I can update it by using google cloud console and from the advanced settings of the method.

However, when I deploy the new version of the method, timeout setting is again 60 seconds and I need to update this field after each deployment of the method.

Any way which I can set the timeout duration per function will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your firebase-tools module to at least version [3.15.3](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v3.15.3), where this bug was fixed for the CLI.  You can always get the latest version like this:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@latest
```